# How do you delete Phabricator project or task

Tags: phabricator

I use Phabricator for code review, but I can't delete a project once it was created. The only thing I can do is change the project status from active to archived. The other problem is Task, same to project, I can't delete a task once it was created.

Sometimes, people try to test Phabricator, maybe he or she creates some mock projects, it makes sense to delete them after testing.

Answer (score 32):

It is possible, but only by using the command line administration tools.

Remove a task? `./phabricator/bin/remove destroy TASK-ID` (ie: T1, T23)

Remove a project? `./phabricator/bin/remove destroy PHID-PROJ-6i6ofxwwz4xybdvg7oa5`

Here is how to find the PHID: [How do you find the PHID of a Phabricator object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753749/how-do-you-find-the-phid-of-a-phabricator-object)

Comment: Can you please explain how to get a PHID? This answer is not useful otherwise.

Comment: And be careful, especially since you said you want to delete a project. The delete is **not** smart or recursive. You may end up with a bunch of orphaned tasks not connected to any project. Everything in Phabricator is connected, and breaking connections by just deleting things is dangerous because it leaves loose ends behind. But you probably already know that. And if you don't, you'll see a stern warning when you run `bin/remove destroy`!

Comment: can you please explain me what I have to install in order to have the command "remove" in bin folder? I only have arcanist installed , and I do not have that command

Comment: @Apperside this is part of the phabricator source code. You can find all the commands that is available over here : https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/tree/64b399d9be2684c4dad39fe8bab482434cd9fcf1/bin. Just like how you would run ./bin/storage for initial DB setup we can use remove command as well.

Answer (score 9):

I've asked the Phabricator developer on IRC, user can't delete a project or task, this is designed on purpose, the only way to do it is archive project or close task. Refer to his reply as below:

> We do not plan to add that feature, the feature would create a lot of problems. For example, some user could delete your stuff and you'd have no way to tell who did it. If a user closes or archives your stuff, it says "alincoln closed this task." Another problem is that a project may have thousands or millions of objects attached to it. If you delete the project, either all of those objects become attached to an empty/invalid project, or we need to run some sort of background cleanup process. And there's no way to undo deletion, so users who make mistakes can't recover from it.