# How do you find the PHID of a Phabricator object?

Tags: phabricator

I need to get the PHIDs for one project and several users in our Phabricator install. It seems like it should be trivial to find out how to do this, but I've searched the docs to no avail. Am I looking in the wrong place or something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Easiest way:

1. Go to the project
2. Click New Task
3. Look at the URL, it will have a parameter like:

   ```
    ?projects=PHID-PROJ-owipizovyry4fatifwfd
   ```

- PHID is "PHID-PROJ-owipizovyry4fatifwfd"

Option 2:

1. Go to your Conduit at `https://phabricator.example/conduit`
2. Find the method `project.query`
3. Enter the name in a JSON encoded array (i.e. ["project name"])
4. Click Call Method
5. PHID will be one of the data elements:

   ```
    {
      "data"    : {
        "PHID-PROJ-oybqquyhhke4awiw2akz" : {
          "id"           : "19",
          "phid"         : "PHID-PROJ-oybqquyhhke4awiw2akz",
          "name"         : "project name",
          "members"      : [
            "PHID-USER-gapak5h34h6d5yvl67dx",
            "PHID-USER-674vq754zfuhyxgvvq7x",
            "PHID-USER-qvcdsyc4oz7rzpzziiyk",
            "PHID-USER-qmefzjtsrmnxjxpc45km",
            "PHID-USER-pbhygge7rgpdowz3s5vk"
          ],
          "slugs"        : [
            "project_name"
          ],
          "dateCreated"  : "1396666703",
          "dateModified" : "1396668261"
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The second method also works to find PHIDs of users.

Comment: any similar way to determine PHID of a dashboard?

Comment: It doesn't seem that they do. :( That's one of the few I haven't tried until just now and it doesn't work.

Comment: I have problem to find PHID of diffusion, any idea?

Comment: This should probably be asked as it's own question... in Conduit, there is a method named `phid.lookup`.  If you go there and enter your repo name(s) (or key(s)), you will find a similar output.  for repos you are looking for rABC type key.  For example, if I was on https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/phid.lookup/ and I wanted to know about the Phabricator repo, I would enter this for the name: `["rP"]` and I would get a json response that included the PHID (and a few other details).  If you create a question, please post the link so I can answer officially.

Answer (score 9):

A more robust method would be to call the conduit method `phid.lookup`:

```
https://<your install>/conduit/method/phid.lookup/
```

Then enter in `names` something like `@user`, `#project` or `Z2` and you'll get the PHID.