# How to delete Phabricator Pholio Mock

Tags: phabricator

I want to remove a mock created using Pholio in Phabricator.

I have found a way to delete projects or tasks described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640670), but cant figure out how to delete a mock.

The url of my mock is mydomain/M1 so I tried to execute the command 
  
  `./phabricator/bin/remove destroy M1`
but the output of the command was "No such file or directory"

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates you are not running the command from the correct directory.  When I run my destroy command, I browse to the location I have installed Phabricator to and run the command `./bin/remove destroy ...`

Comment: Thanks!! I had installed phabricator in another directory named phabricator and got mixed up